# Magento 2.4 upgrade Class 'Zend_Controller_Request_Http' not found

Tags: magento2, upgrade, magento2.4

I recently updated from Magento 2.2 to Magento 2.4 and I have some custom modules which are throwing errors like these when I run `setup:di:compile` in my terminal. I have observed that in `vendor` folder the `zendframework` is now changed to `zendframework1`. However I cannot understand how to find the file and resolve this error. My custom modules extend `Zend_Controller_Request_Http`. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I am facing the same issue after i upgraded magento 2.1 to 2.4.2, did you find any resolution for this ?